# expressjs and socket.io session issues

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm using express and socket.io and I want to share the express session between the two, with each one being on a different Node instance (localhost:3000 and localhost:8000). So far, express will create the session and the cookie created, however socket.io only picks up the 'io' cookie, not the express cookie. Can anyone show mw here my error is? I'm using express 4.x and socket.io 1.x.

Express config (localhost:3000):

```
var cookieParser    = require('cookie-parser')
  , session         = require('express-session')
  , bodyParser      = require('body-parser')
  , express         = require('express')
  , redis           = require('redis')
  , RedisStore      = require('connect-redis')(session);

module.exports = function (app, passport) {

app.use(express.static('./static'))
app.use(cookieParser("thisismynewsecret"));
app.use(session({
    //passport: passport,
    name: 'sid',
    //key: 'express.sid',
    secret: 'thisismynewsecret',
    saveUinitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redis.createClient() }),
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        path: '/',
        secure: false
    }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)
app.set('views', './views')
app.set('view engine', 'jade')

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(require('method-override')());
app.use( require('express-subdomain-handler')({ baseUrl: 'localhost', prefix: 'myprefix', logger: true }) );  
}
});
```

socket.io (localhost:8000):

```
var fs              = require('fs');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookie = require('cookie');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var sessionStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

var server = require('http').Server(function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/views/JAMinit.html', function(error, content) {
if (error) {
  res.writeHead(500);
  res.end();
}
else {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
  res.end(content, 'utf-8');
}
 });
}).listen(8000);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.use(function(socket, next) {
var data = socket.handshake || socket.request;

if (data.headers.cookie) {
    data.cookie = cookie.parse(cookieParser.signedCookie(data.headers.cookie, 'thisismynewsecret'));
    console.log(data.cookie);
    console.log('data.cookies ( %s )', JSON.stringify(data.cookie));

    if (data.cookie.sid) {
        data.sid = data.headers.cookie.sid;
        sessionStore.get(data.headers.cookie.sid, function(err, session) {
            data.session = session;
        });
    }
}

next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [express.io](http://express-io.org/), it combines express and socket.io and has [automatic session support](https://github.com/techpines/express.io#automatic-session-support).